# Should I upload the checklist document generated by the website of UK Visa?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I will apply for Standard Visit Visa to do a research visit. I used self-service to upload my documents.

Should I upload the checklist document generated by the website of UK Visa ? Or is not necessary?

Comment: I assume it's a document listing all the documents you have to provide. If I understand it correctly, you don't need to submit that...

Comment: @Johnnyjanko It lists the mandatory document (passport/travel document) plus provides space for the applicant to detail any other documents they are providing in support of the application. So yes, I would complete and upload the checklist, assuming that the self-service system doesn’t offer another option to detail the documents. But I’ve never used the self-service upload system, so not posting as an answer.